# Simple DE with separable variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is my first de experience, so I need someone to help me with initial conditions, I have:
$$y'=ky \quad k \ne 0$$

so what I did:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= ky \\
dy &= kydx\\
\frac{dy}{y} &= kdx \\
\int\frac{dy}{y} &= k\int dx \\
\ln|y| &= kx +С \\
|y| &= e^{kx+С}
\end{align*}$$

How do I proceed? Am I right with previous steps?

Comment: You missed the $+C$ when you integrated the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have $\ln|y| = kx+C$, and so $|y| = e^{kx+C}$.

Laws of exponents tell us that $e^{kx+C} = e^{kx} \times e^C$, so $|y| = e^{kx} \times e^C$.

Since $C$ is a constant, so too is $e^C$, so let's re-label it as $A$.

This gives $|y| = Ae^{kx}$, where $A > 0$ ($A=e^C$ and $e^C > 0$ for all real $C$)

We can drop the modulus on the LHS, as long as we let $A$ be any real number:

$$y = Ae^{kx}$$

Comment: +1 Definitely a good idea to drop the $|\;|$.  In fact, even $A=0$ is OK for the original differential equation, but not for this solution method.  So a stickler might say the third line $\int\frac{dy}{y} = k\int dx$ should have another clause: "or $y=0$"